# How to insert multiple records at once using DataSet and DataAdapter in vb.net & ms access?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, oledb

i was trying to insert record from one table to another using Data Set, first here's the code:

```
 Try
            Dim ds1 As New DataSet
            Dim dbada2 As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dbbl2 As New OleDbCommandBuilder
            Dim dbcon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbconstring)

            dbcon.Open()
            Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT InspectionID, ICTDIR, UnitDescription, SizeType, QuantityNo, SerialNo FROM DeliveryInspection WHERE ICTDIR = @ictdir", dbcon)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ictdir", txtRefNo.Text)
            Dim dbada1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1)
            ds1.Clear()
            dbada1.Fill(ds1)
            dbcon.Close()

            dbcon.Open()
            dbada2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LogSUF", dbcon)
            dbada2.Update(ds1)
            dbcon.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "DBADA 2 Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

here i have 2 DataAdapters, The first one is from the table `DeliveryInspection` and the second is from `LogSUF`. both tables have the same Column with the only difference is that `LogSUF` has no records.

I want to make a system that will insert a record from `DeliveryInspection` (with the corresponding `ICTDIR` from the Text Box where the user typed it which is `txtRefNo`) to the `LogSUF`. My code doesn't have error but it doesn't work either and i tried some ways to fix this problem. Please help and also is there another way to do this? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Update`, only the rows with a `RowState` of `Added`, `Modified` or `Deleted` will be saved. As it stands, all your rows have a `RowState` of `Unchanged`, so there's nothing to save.

The solution is to set `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `False` on the first data adapter, before you call `Fill`. That way, the `AcceptChanges` method is not called implicitly when you call `Fill` and each `RowState` will remain `Added`, ready for the row to be inserted when you call `Update`.

Comment: I've been searching for weeks for this paragraph of information.  So many thanks.